# How do I move the blockchain file location on Windows?

Tags: blockchain, client

I tried to edit the storage information for the blockchain. Neither the Windows 7 nor *Bitcoin qt* could do it (it says that the app can't open the configuration file).

So I tried to edit the `-datadir` in in *Bitcoin qt*. The app doesn't give me a response for the command (I thought it had worked but the blockchain was yet being download in my desktop).

I don't know how to create the symbolic link that someone has wrote in another question. Can someone give me some information that I may had misread?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings > Options and click the `Reset Options` Button. Note that this will clear all of the options shown there, so note down what they all are so you can set your options again later.

In the Dialog that appears, click Yes and Bitcoin Core will shut down. Now go to the Bitcoin data directory and copy the entire thing to wherever you want it to be. The data directory on Windows is located at `%APPDATA%\Bitcoin`. Move the contents of the data directory to the location you want Bitcoin Core's data to be.

Start Bitcoin Core again. You should be prompted to choose the data directory. Choose a Custom data directory and set it to wherever you moved the data directory to. Then set your options again.

Comment: The simplest way worked haha, thanks Andrew.

Comment: Will reseting options affect pruning?